# Add URL parameter to all routes with middleware

Tags: php, apache, laravel, middleware, laravel-5.5

I am trying to add a url parameter to all my routes on laravel 5.5 using middleware.

The parameter had to stay the same after switching routes.

I tried to use redirect in the middleware but it was just adding to the url the default value of my parameter without looking if it changed

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (!str_contains($request->getRequestUri(), 'persona=') && str_contains($request->getRequestUri(), '?'))
    {
        $url = str_replace($request->getBaseUrl(), '', $request->getRequestUri());
        return redirect($url."&persona=".$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']);
    }
    if (!str_contains($request->getRequestUri(), 'persona=') && !str_contains($request->getRequestUri(), '?'))
    {
        $url = str_replace($request->getBaseUrl(), '', $request->getRequestUri());
        return redirect($url."?persona=".$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']);
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

with this function the parameter will always take the value "$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']" because it can't see that the parameter was here on the last requested url.

EDIT: I found a better way to have a following parameter, i tried by modifying the laravel function "route", "url" and "action", it works good but sometimes the parameter disappear so if there is a better way i'm interested.

Comment: Hi, have you resolved the issue?